# JRE это исполнительная система или это среда выполнения?

Tags: java, терминология

Начнем с JDK:

> Java Development Kit (сокращенно JDK) — бесплатно распространяемый
>   компанией Oracle Corporation (ранее Sun Microsystems) комплект
>   разработчика приложений на языке Java, включающий в себя компилятор
>   Java (javac), стандартные библиотеки классов Java, примеры,
>   документацию, различные утилиты и **исполнительную систему Java (JRE)**.

JRE:

> Java Runtime Environment (сокр. JRE; русск. **среда выполнения для Java**)
>   — минимальная реализация виртуальной машины, необходимая для
>   исполнения Java-приложений, без компилятора и других средств
>   разработки. Состоит из виртуальной машины — Java Virtual Machine — и
>   библиотеки Java-классов.

Так как понять всё-таки, JRE это исполнительная система Java или это среда выполнения для Java?

В JDK одно написано, в JRE другое. Весь материал взят из Википедии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исполнительная система и среда выполнения - это одно и то же.

Answer (score 0):

В моем понимании JRE нужен для разработчика, чтобы проекты запускать в режиме рантайм. Чтобы при редактировании вам не было необходимости пересобират ьпроект 10 раз. Чтобы деплоя например было достаточно. Я могу быть не прав конечно, но я понимаю это как-то так.

ну а JDK для самого пользователя продукта, что бы запускать java приложения.

Comment: Я знаю что такое JDK, просто про JRE копаю глубже чтобы понять конкретней.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван так как он содержит JVM, могу сказать что благодаря JRE вы можете запускать веб приложения на java, деплоить их без компиляции проекта. Я если честно сам не особо вникал в это. По крайней мер это что я знаю о JRE.

Comment: Что такое деплой?

Comment: Как раз наоборот. JDK - для разработки. Так ведь и написано - Developer Kit - набор разработчика. А JRE - среда исполнения, не требующая компилятора итд. Она - для запуска приложений (например, исполняемых .jar-файлов. Ну и набор библиотек для запуска нужен, чтобы JVM знала что куда